# Missing Csrf token cookie

Tags: cakephp, cookies, csrf, middleware, cakephp-3.7

I'm relatively new to CakePHP (v3.7).  I have an application in which I'm getting a "Missing Csrf Token Cookie" error.

In Application.php, I have:

```
$options = [];        // I'm fine with the default options.
$csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware($options);
$middlewareQueue->add($csrf);
```

The form page has a hidden form element with the *_csrfToken* in it.
I'm confused as to why it's not being found on the POST?

Digging further, I found that in *CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php*, the *_validateToken()* function below behaves as follows:

*$cookies* is *null* (there are no cookies set.)
thus, *$cookie* is *null*.

*$post* actually contains the content of the *_csrfToken* parameter from the hidden parameter on the page.  However the function never looks at it.  Because *$cookie* is null,
the *if(!$cookie)* statement causes an *InvalidCsrfTokenException* to be thrown.

```
    protected function _validateToken(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $cookies = $request->getCookieParams();
        $cookie = Hash::get($cookies, $this->_config['cookieName']);
        $post = Hash::get($request->getParsedBody(), $this->_config['field']);
        $header = $request->getHeaderLine('X-CSRF-Token');

        if (!$cookie) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException(__d('cake', 'Missing CSRF token cookie'));
        }

        if (!Security::constantEquals($post, $cookie) && !Security::constantEquals($header, $cookie)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException(__d('cake', 'CSRF token mismatch.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, the middleware is expecting an *actual* cookie, in addition to a hidden parameter.  Where is this cookie set (or supposed to be set?)

Update:

I checked on the browser side.  The cookie is being set, but the browser isn't returning it on the POST request.

Here's CakePHP's RESPONSE to the original GET request to populate the page:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 3013
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 08 May 2019 23:07:31 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.1.1
Set-Cookie: csrfToken=b553dd2e06e57f6d514ee41a120e1c60084adafddfbaa6f72db1f7f590fcf50143876ac817d29d6f1cf9a786031d6235ba21e265b9d3b2a0ee4535854f048b66; path=/webroot/
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.1
```

Note the csrfToken cookie.
... and here's the POST that the browser sends back with the form data

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Host: *************
Origin: ****************
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: ***************
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36
```

Query String Parameters

```
redirect: /Users/login
```

Form Data

```
_method: POST
_csrfToken:  b553dd2e06e57f6d514ee41a120e1c60084adafddfbaa6f72db1f7f590fcf50143876ac817d29d6f1cf9a786031d6235ba21e265b9d3b2a0ee4535854f048b66
username: xxxxxxxxxx
password: xxxxxxxxxx
```

Note that it's sending back the hidden form parameter *_csrfToken*, but NOT the cookie.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: The cookie is being set in the middlewares `_addTokenCookie()` method, which is being invoked from the `__invoke()` method when the current request is a `GET` request, and the cookie isn't already present in the current request.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In my case the request is a POST, so (presumably, and by evidence) no cookie is being set.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Your first request (the one that creates the form) should be a `GET` request  (otherwise there would also be no token), the `POST` request that submits the form should then have the cookie.

Comment: The first request is a GET. (e.g., I can type the form url directly into the browser address bar.)

Comment: And does the response to that request contain the cookie (check your browsers network tab)? If so, is it being sent when submitting the form (again, check in browsers network tab)?

Comment: The cookie is being set on the browser, but the browser isn't returning it.  I added the detail to the original post.

Comment: The cookie path says `/webroot/`, which is pretty unusual. Is that really your public path, ie does your URL look like `/webroot/etc...`? If not, then that's the problem, the browser won't sent the cookie if the path isn't in the request URL.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  It turns out my Apache DOCUMENT_ROOT was set to a level above /webroot.  It should have been at webroot.  As soon as I changed it everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a problem with the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory setting in Apache.  It was set to the parent directory of webroot, instead of to webroot itself.  When I changed it everything worked.